# No web page is shown although the pipeline runs fine in the web project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, webapi

My web home page will not show up anymore in my .net core 8 project.

The best message I could find was in Edge:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

I have checked and the response object does return a 200 (OK) code in the Web.Program class.

[200 code response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A12eS.png)

[this is my repo](https://github.com/marcos-csdev/Microservices)

I have changed the `launchSettings.json` file value with the project URL, but that part seems to be fixed now that the response returns 200.

I have also checked out the default routes in the Web.Program class, but all seems fine.

The expected return is the default .NET Core home page with very few visual changes.

Repro steps:

1. Set the Microservices.Web project as startup project if needed
2. Run the application on IIS
3. Although no error is shown, the view is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

I check the code in Github. From your `program.cs`, You seems to wanna when the url can't map to controller, it will redirect to index page, So you can modify your code to:

```
       var app = builder.Build();
       //......other middleware

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Home");
            }
        });

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        
        app.Run();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! That is just a conditional to get the response from the server. it is not important to the actual application. Unfortunately, your suggestion didn't work. Please keep me posted if you have more ideas.

Comment: I want to make sure that the project is `Microservices.Web`, It is a mvc project,  When you run this project, it can't load the home index page correctly?

Comment: That's correct. Just run the Microservices.Web project (set it as startup project if needed) and you can see that, although everything seems fine, the page is not loaded. It doesn't hit the HomeController, so it seems that there is something wrong with the routing.

Comment: Have you checked the order of middleware is correct? `app.Use(){}` need to come before  `app.MapControllerRoute()`

Comment: Yes, I have placed the code you suggested, the view is still not loaded.

Comment: strange, Could you update your github so i can test your current code.

Comment: I have created a new web project, pasted the folders from the previous project and the new one works. I'll commit the changes right now.

Comment: In your new web project, have you tried to add the code i suggested? I test and works fine.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it works now. Thank you very much for all your help.